# Excel find last in row when not consecutive columns

Tags: excel

Is there a way without using vba to return the last column in a row with data when the items searched for are each 8 columns apart. Ex. I want the last value of A3,I3,Q3,Y3,AG3,AO3,AW3,BE3,BM3,BU3,CC3,CK3 and CS3.

Thanks

Comment: Are they numbers or text?

Comment: And is there data in other cells  other than those?

Comment: What it is, is a series of items monthly each set of 8 columns represents the same data for the month.  Ex name and number of sales of multiple items each in own column. So both text and numbers. I'm trying to get these to a defined location to report on in another sheet, without needing to update the reference location each time.

Comment: An example of the data and expected outcome would help.